# Условно обязательные поля

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

```js
interface A extends Partial<B> {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface B {
  c: string;
  d: string;
}
```

Возможно ли как-то по-другому определить интерфейс А, чтоб если в переменной данного типа есть поле "c" или "d", то оба поля становятся обязательными?

Answer (score 1):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=60&pc=1#code/LYewJgrgNgpgBAdwIYE84G8BQc4wB4AOIATgC5xgwDGUSx8AbnXEgDRwBG7V7Y7MAbkwBfTJlCRYiVADoASgEkA4gAkAKhmxwAlgDtSMYgDMkVeAEFNOHEgBccAM6liegOZDrne05e73WnCowAH57ACEtUS09A2NTeDCraypvZzcPazBU338cKMCQXScWAAZ7SwBeDBZ2DjhRAqLyJABGcrgq9BZ6rSpC4qQAJnbOms5uLOqqep6o8XBoeGQUGV09ACskJJjDEzM4ABItrrZOHpwduP2Duq6eCh6tUhQCeBuAaRgUBw64AGsviAjIcOE8Xm8kJ9vr8ASggYckGDXrg8M5TAYwFCHAAeNQAPl%20AFFUcR0djYfC1OwPl8HHikRZcQSqsS0VRSOTAcCqSCsQT8AZdGAfroYAxDAE4ME4BBdH9dCAELpJfYBaT2TBMbSmSjBcLebSpSC4PZZfLFcqcM9kWEdSySWSKdzqZDafzUTAhSKxRLPNKzQqlSrdeqMVidQLPfqjlijUcTTK5YHLXBrUsEAg7XBzDqAGRwW34sQ4AD0JbggA4QQCCIIB%20EEAfCCAbhBADIggHYQQDCIIBOEDggFkQQBCIHWtJQaHR4EZZeztIVOHQmQAKACO9gACnRSNokFBsfH8zcCfmM5n8QBKexqLRlysNis9-uD6i0ehwMe6CdTowgEBzxdwDT7jNMk8f3Pcsa0AARBAAYQQAmEArZtAF4QOs4EARhBAGkQOBe3AwAuEHYeC4FgwBWEDgCDELrdC8N7YCKHvEcn3HNc3w-XFdSjH4VzIddN23EE8TxBdTzgP9DzxQCz1LcsAFoJMkqTJOLOBvywTwLwAAVIBwxPwV52XU4hiBISVYHIecSl%20Dg6FnE5am4Xh%20HqI84AvAB5Dh1mocgoG0WINzgYBUDgQooDQBxNO0Iw0HNJU4AIXTXjYmAHHYJAhTgAByGBkooEA4rgBVyHwbRij0VNwRS1i1w3Lcth3Dg8WSmRZ0GABmAAWABWI9JQvMTWDEjryxUtSNNc7TdOIfSYEMlpfnfEBzLGLg4HuPhcFssbDMGKaP1m055sWlbPAMuSGo2maLPGBbbPs8sl2iwxnhSsB0vy7z8ocNwdF0IrkWSm5avq5q2tWuSmuOrbaj26wDvnFqQZOC6L2ukAYru5KOEen5gBet7CrTFKjl%20xrWvavIRDETAgA)

```
module way {
  export declare var a, b, c, d, e;
}

module way.RIGHT {
  interface A {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    cd?: B
  }

  interface B {
    c: string;
    d: string;
  }

  const a0: A = { a, b }
  const a1: A = { a }
  const a2: A = { a, b, cd: { c } }
}


module way.ninja {
  interface $a { a, b }
  interface $b { c, d }

  type $bKeys = keyof $b
  type $aKeys = keyof $a
  type extractedKeys<T> = Extract<keyof T, $bKeys>
  type A<T> = Extract<keyof T, $bKeys> extends never
    ? unknown
    : extractedKeys<T> extends $bKeys ? $b : unknown
  type B<T> = Extract<keyof T, $aKeys> extends never
    ? unknown
    : extractedKeys<T> extends $aKeys ? $a : unknown
  type www<T> = A<T> & B<T>

  // используй это
  declare function bar<T>(q: Partial<$a & $b> & www<T>): T
  // или это
  declare function foo<T>(q: T & www<T>): T
  // правильно бы так, но не работает
  // declare function foo<T extends Partial<$a & $b>>(q: T & www<T>): T
  // -------------

  q: {
    // @ts-expect-error
    let q0 = bar({ a, b, c, d, e }) // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'e' does not exist in type 'Partial<$a & $b>'.(2345)
    // -,-
    // @ts-expect-error
    let q1 = foo({ a, b, c, d, e }) // нет ошибки
    let q2 = foo({ a, b, c, d })
    let q3 = foo({ a, b, c }) // Property 'd' is missing in type '$b'.(2345)
    let q4 = foo({ a, b })
    let q5 = foo({ a }) // Property 'b' is missing in type '$a'.(2345)
  }
}
```

### upd

```
module way.RIGHT2 {
  interface A { a, b }
  interface B extends A { c, d }

  type $fooProps = { a?: A, b?: B }
  function foo({ a, b }: $fooProps) {
    if (a && b) throw new TypeError('fooProps nust have a or b')
    else if (b) {
      // -
    } else if (a) {
      // -
    } else {
      throw new TypeError('fooProps nust have a or b')
    }
  }
  foo({ a: { a, b } })
  foo({ b: { a, b, c, d } })
}
```

### UPD 2. что-то я классы обделил вниманием

пожалуй, это самый верный путь

```
module way.RIGHT22 {
    class A {
        a; b; c?; d?;
        constructor(...[a, b, c, d]: [string, string] | [string, string, string, string]) {
            this.a = a
            this.b = b
            this.c = c
            this.d = d
        }
    }
    test: {
        new A('') // err
        new A('', '', '') // err
        new A('', '', '', '', '') // err

        new A('', '') // ok
        new A('', '', '', '') // ok
    }
}
```